# Parent.Profile.Name and object Object

Tags: apex, soql, profile

Using this query to obtain permission on profile but getting [object Object] for the Parent.Profile.Name. Seen other post but still not able to show the name. Running from dev console if that still makes a difference ?

```
SELECT Id, SobjectType, Parent.label, Parent.Profile.Name,
PermissionsCreate, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete,
PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsModifyAllRecords
FROM ObjectPermissions 
WHERE parentid in (select id from permissionset where
PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'MY PROFILE NAME')
```

Comment: Developer console doesn't show reference fields property, you may have to use work query in workbench or some other tool.

Comment: Thanks. Thought this was the case. Will throw the query into a VisualForce page . Looks better anyway.

Comment: The same problem exists if you run from sfdx command line, for instance: `sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, Parent.Label, Parent.IsOwnedByProfile, SobjectType, PermissionsRead FROM ObjectPermissions'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your query, it's just as Raul mentioned. The problem comes from the fact that you are running it in the Developer Console.

I simplified your query just for this example to only query for `Parent.Profile.Name` and I put a LIMIT 1:

```
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name
FROM ObjectPermissions 
WHERE parentid in (select id from permissionset where
PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
LIMIT 1
```

Here's what I get when I run the query in Dev Console:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSRnp.png]

If I run the same query using a different tool(in this case I am using [organizer](https://organizer.enree.co/index.html) for Chrome):

[image]